# Most efficient way to replace last SubString of a String from a list of another strings in Java

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a list of string (more than 5000 in count) example listed below, these string are separated by an equal "=" delimiter, and left side of delimiter is the string that i need to check with end of another String and if there is an match then i need to replace it with right side of the string.

```
,.LLC=LLC
D.E.F.=DEF
&,Aida.=AID
&ECho,MA=ECHO
```

Example:

1. If string is `HelloD.E.F.` than it should be replace by `HELLO DEF`
2. If string is `Hello&ECho,MA` than it should be replace by `HELLO ECHO`

Need to find the most efficient way to get it done. Rather than iterating all the string recursively. (Efficient in time consumption, memory consumption is not a issue.)

Comment: I have tried by storing this in Arraylist and then comparing it with the String to get it done.

Comment: show the code you've tried in your question

Comment: If you want to match many patterns exactly, the Aho-Corasick algorithm could be the solution. Or Rabin-Karp. Both have been designed for matching multiple, pre-processed patterns simultaneously.

Comment: i will check on this ..might be a best solution for my problem..Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of reasonable ways to do it, depending on your exact requirements.  Personally I wouldn't do this in Java at all; I would convert your `=` delimited patterns into [`sed`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sed) replacements, e.g.:

```
s/,.LLC/LLC/
s/D.E.F./DEF/
s/&,Aida./AID/
s/&ECho,MA/ECHO/
```

You might have to do some additional escaping depending on the exact strings; e.g. `\` and `(` are special.  Once you have your `sed`-style expressions simply pass in your input strings and you'll get out your desired strings:

```
$ sed -f list_of_patterns.txt list_of_strings.txt
```

---

If you really need to do this in Java you'll probably want to parse the replacements into a `Map<String, String>`, then loop over your strings, checking their suffixes one-by-one for matches in your map.  Start with the last character, then the last two, last three, and so on.  If you find a match you can concatenate the rest of the string (before the matched suffix) with the corresponding value in the map.

This is O(1) on the number of replacements, but O(n) on the number of characters in the strings you need to replace.

Comment: This again will work only with O(n) ..

  HashMap<String,String> al = new HashMap<String,String>();
  al.put(",.LLC","LLC");
  al.put("D.E.F.","DEF");
  al.put("&,Aida.","AID");
  al.put("&ECho,MA","ECHO");
  
  String inputString = "HelloD.E.F.";
  
  if(al.keySet().contains(inputString)){  
   System.out.println(" Working ");
  }
  else
   System.out.println(" not working ");

Comment: Below is working:--

  Iterator iterator = al.keySet().iterator();
  while(iterator.hasNext()){
    Object key   = iterator.next();
    Object value = al.get(key);
    
    if(inputString.contains(key.toString()))
    {
     System.out.println(" Working ");     
    }
  }

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking; if you have code snippets edit them into your question, comments are impossible to read.

Comment: I notice you're doing `al.keySet().contains(inputString)` which isn't going to work.  First, `Map` has a [`.containsKey()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#containsKey-java.lang.Object-) method, you don't need to use the `keySet()`; second, you need to call `.containsKey()` on the string's suffixes; e.g. `al.containsKey(string.substring(string.length()-6, string.length())` will return `true`.  You need to loop over each suffix substring to find the matching suffix.

Comment: But there is no way i can get the value of 6 for (string.length()-6 .. as value of 6 will vary for each input key ..so it will not work.

Comment: Like I said, you need to loop over the input string. Start with the last character, then the last two, and so on.